# How to compare date (yyyy-mm-dd) with year-Quarter (yyyyQQ) in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a sql query using pandas within python. In the where clause I need to compare a date column (say review date 2016-10-21) with this value '2016Q4'. In other words if the review dates fall in or after Q4 in 2016 then they will be selected. Now how do I convert the review date to something comparable to 'yyyyQ4' format. Is there any python function for that ? If not, how so I go about writing one for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are able to get the month out into a variable: mon

you can use the following code to get the quarter information:

`for mon in range(1, 13):
  print (mon-1)//3 + 1,
print`

which would return:

- for months 1 - 3    : 1
- for months 4 - 6    : 2
- for months 7 - 9    : 3
- for months 10 - 12  : 4

Comment: I can see how this is working for a range. But if I have  column/data frame named 'month' (with values ranging from 1 to 12) how should I use the for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Id suggest converting your Review date to a quarter format. Then checking if they are equal.

Example

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())) + 'Q' + 
        CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 3 THEN '1'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 6 THEN '2'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 9 THEN '3'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 12 THEN '4' 
        END)
```

You can use that in a where like this, just replace GETDATE() with your review date column and '2018Q1' with your quarter column

```
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())) +  CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 3 THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 6 THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 9 THEN 'Q3'
            WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(M,GETDATE())) <= 12 THEN 'Q4' 
        END) = '2018Q1'
```

Comment: Ideally maybe this solution would have worked and I was also thinking in the same line but DATEPART is not working when used within pd.read_sql() and shows this error:No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.